# grsecurity effieffectiveness test with latest proftpd remote exploit

Tags: ftp, exploit, grsec

i just tested grsecurity. i installed debian and a vulnerable version of proftpd. i launched an exploit. worked. patched the latest kernel with grsec. and now the exploit doesnt work anymore. BUT . wouldnt just a the new kernel alone cause the exploit to fail? the exploit was only for debian sqzeeze and one special version of proftpd??

Comment: Thinking you'll get interest if you post this over in security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did work!

didnt see it in the remote shell but directly on the server

http://webservsec.blogspot.com/2011/01/grsecurity-vs-proftpd-exploit.html